# PowerShell way to get the Alert Resolution States in SCOM 2007?

Tags: powershell, alerts, scom, system-center

I was wondering if there was a command like the Get-SCOMAlertResolutionState on SCOM2012, but in SCOM2007.

I cannot find a way to do this in powershell. Doing this through the GUI is so easy that there must be a way to get this through powershell, or a SQL Query.

What I want is what you fin in: Operations Manager Console->Administration->Alerts->Alert Resolution States.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it works with OpsMgr 2007, but in 2007 R2 you can retrieve the Alert in question with `Get-Alert`, and inspect the `ResolutionState` property:

```
PS> $alerts = Get-Alert
PS> $alerts[0].ResolutionState
255
PS>
```

0 means "New", 255 is the "Resolved" state